# c programming, memory lost after reading file

Tags: c

This is part of my c code, the program is to read a file of keywords separated by lines and store them into an array of string.....

```
int keyno = 4;
char *keywords[keyno];
char var[100];
i=0;
while(fgets(var, sizeof(var), k)!=NULL){   //k is the file
    printf("var: %s", var);
    if(i>0)
        keywords[i-1]=var;
    printf("keyword: %s", keywords[i-1]);
    i++;
}

for (i=0; i<keyno;i++)
    printf("keyword: %s", keywords[i]);
```

**result:**

```
var:
keyword: (null)
var: abc
keyword: abc
var: def
keyword: def
var: ghi
keyword:ghi
var: jkl
keyword: jkl
var:
keyword: @-g(?)

keyword: @-g(?) keyword: @-g(?) keyword: @-g(?) keyword: @-g(?)
```

why the keywords are gone in the forloop...?  what line should i add?

Comment: The pointers of `keywords` `char` pointer array pointing to same variable `var`. Hence, you are getting the output as last value of `var`. Make `keywords` 2D array and copy the `var` to `keywords[]` array.

Comment: After you now have been given some hints, you might show what you tried ([mcve]) and update the code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *keywords[keyno];
```

is an array of pointers.

In the loop at this line

```
keywords[i-1]=var;
```

you make all pointers in `keywords` point to `var`. So when you print `keywords` you actually just print `var` multiple times.

Instead you could do

```
char keywords[keyno][100];
```

and copy like:

```
strcpy(keywords[i-1], var);
```

Comment: The key point is that each of the keyword pointers ends up pointing at the same space for the string, which can only hold the last value stored in it.  You're right that a 2D array of characters is one to deal with.  Using POSIX function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) is also a way to handle it — though the memory would need to be freed too.  You can easily implement `strdup()` if it isn't available: `char *strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *dup = malloc(len); if (dup != 0) memmove(dup, str, len); return dup; }`.

Comment: @ycsjose: I recommend reading up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There are all sorts of ways you could be running into compilation errors or warnings, or perhaps runtime errors if you ignore the compile time warnings.  We can't begin to guess which clever and non-obvious tricks you've used to fool the compiler — novice programmers are far too clever to be easily predicted by us.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array like this

```
char* keywords[keyno];
```

You are declaring an array of pointers to strings. However the pointers need to point somewhere
and each pointer needs to point to a different location.

```
keywors[i-1]=var;
```

makes each pointer point to the same address, the address of the array `var`

to fix this, allocate memory when you get something from the file.

e.g.

```
keywords[i-1] = malloc(strlen(var)+1); /* allocate memory */
strcpy(keywords[i-1], var);  /* copy to the newly allocated memory */
```

later you need to free that memory

```
for (int i = 0; i < keyno; ++i)    
  free(keywords[i[);
```

as a precaution make sure all pointers are set to NULL at the beginning in your program since free on an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior but freeing a NULL pointer is fine.

```
char* keywords[key];
for (int i = 0; i < keyno; ++i)
  keywords[i] = NULL;
...
while(fgets(var, sizeof(var), k)!=NULL){  ... }
...
for (int i = 0; i < keyno; ++i)    
  free(keywords[i[);
```